# how do I implement a else part in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to implement an else part when there are no references, and display `no data is available` , but i am currently using reactjs with typescript , how do I implement this check?

```
<div className="overview-text">
<div className="overview-text-header">References</div>
{data.reference.map((reference) => (
    <div className="overview-text-item" key={reference}>{urlParser(reference)}</div> // if there is no data then no data available
))}
</div>
```

Comment: `{data?.reference ? data.reference.map(...) : <span>No data</span>}`

Comment: What did you try and what happened? Did you get an error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ternary operator in jsx to include html with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084658/ternary-operator-in-jsx-to-include-html-with-react)

Comment: You know [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) exists, right?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<div>
  { 
    data.reference && data.reference.length ?
     (if part)
     : (else part)
  }
</div>
```