# How to use ternary condition to render jsx using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to return jsx if some condition is true if not undefined should be returned.

below is my code,

```
const showInfo = (item) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <span>name</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button>click</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
    
const Parent = () => {
    return (
        <Child
            onDone = {({item}) => {
                notify ({
                    actions: (condition === 'value1' || condition === 'value2' ) &&
                        showInfo(item) //should put this condition into showInfo method
                })
            }}
         />
     );
 }
```

**what i am trying to do?**
the above code works. but now i want to put the condition inside the showInfo method. so if condition is true return jsx and if condition is false should return undefined.

**what i have tried?**
I have tried something like below

```
const showInfo = (item) {
    return 
        {(condition === 'value1' || condition === 'value2' ) ? <div>
            <div>
                <span>name</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button>click</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        : undefined
    }
    );
}
    
const Parent = () => {
    return (
        <Child
            onDone = {({item}) => {
                notify ({
                    actions: showInfo(item) //error here
                })
            }}
         />
     );
 }
```

but the above tried code, gives error "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'" at actions statement.

could someone help me with this. i am not sure if i have used ternary operator properly. thanks.

**EDIT**

after trying one of the answers provided,

notify is a method that is returned from usehook
and it evaluates to the component below

```
const Something: React.FC<SomethingProps> = ({
    description,
    actions,
    ...props
}) =>
    (
        <Header>
            <Title>{title}</Title>
        </Header>
        {(description ||actions) && (
            <Body> //this is displayed
                {description && <Description>{description}</Description>}
                {actions && <Actions>{actions}</Actions>}
            </Body>
        )}
    );
```

here the  component is displayed when the condition fails in showInfo component.

in showInfo i am returning undefined if condition fails but still in the Something component the  is displayed even though i have {description || actions}

i am not sure what is happening here.what is the condition i have to check for actions to not display  in this case

i have tried

```
{(description ||actions !== 'false') && (
    <Body> //this is displayed
        {description && <Description>{description}</Description>}
        {actions && <Actions>{actions}</Actions>}
    </Body>
)}
```

and this works. i am wondering why i should specifically mention

```
actions !== 'false'
```

instead of actions only
could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ternary operator in jsx to include html with react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084658/ternary-operator-in-jsx-to-include-html-with-react)

Comment: You're missing a opening parenthesis `(` in the showInfo function right after the return.

Comment: Just use `: null` instead of `: undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return jsx from function you should wrap them inside some component. In this case you cen use **<React.Fragment>** or just **<>**. Another problem which I can see is that you probably forgot about arrow in you arrow function. Also don't know from where variable names `condition` comes from.

```
const showInfo = (item) => {
    return (
      <>
        { condition === "value1" || condition === "value2" ? (
          <div>
            <div>
              <span>name</span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <button>click</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ) : undefined}
      </>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to use the useState or useEffect hooks?